# Keeping differenced value of month for last occuring key

Tags: sql

I have a dataset like this:

```
Month  Key
1          x
1          y
1          z      
2          y
2          z
3          x
3          y
```

I want a dataset like this:

```
Month  Key   Last_occured_before_month
1          x       0    
1          y       0 
1          z       0
2          y       0
2          z       0  
3          x       1  
3          y       0
```

where the in each month, it will look for last occuring value of that key and wherever that month is found it will keep the differenced value.

Comment: Add your database tag,sql is just the language.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `lag()` function.  I think the following does what you want:

```
select month, key,
       coalesce(month - lag(month) over (partition by key order by month) - 1, 0
               ) as Last_occured_before_month
from table t;
```

I do find the -1 curious.  Why would the last line be 3-y-0 instead of 3-y-1?  But, this appears to be the logic you are using.

Comment: I think he wants to count the number of skipped months since the previous occurence.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck . . . That would be the previous month with the key value (minus one), which is what this query does.

Comment: yea., Klas is right. However inbuilt functions like over and partition are not available in SAS SQl

Answer (score 1):

You can use MAX:

```
SELECT Month, Key, NVL((
    SELECT mytable.Month - MAX(t2.Month) - 1
      FROM mytable t2 
     WHERE t2.Key = mytable.Key 
       AND t2.Month < mytable.Month), 0) AS Last_occured_before_month 
  FROM mytable
```

Comment: is NVL any function? it doesnt seem to be available in SAS/SQL

Comment: I used coalesce instead of NVL and its returning 0 for all

Comment: NVL is for Oracle. COALESCE is the same thing, but for MySQL. I missed a specifier on the last reference to Month (should be myTable.Month, not (t2.)Month). Fixed it!